# I want to execute the commands in a loop at the same time, not one after another

Tags: bash, script

I'd like to write a loop ('for') that will do some action 'X' number of times. But instead of performing the actions sequentially, one after another, I'd like them to execute simultaneously (in parellel at the same time). How can this be achieved? Script or a one liner are fine.

example ONLY:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/disk$i bs=10M count=10; done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mostly along the answer `Dennis` gave (+1 there), with your sample case.

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do \
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/disk$i bs=10M count=10 & \
done; wait
```

the '`\`' and new lines are just for reading-pleasure, you can write all that in one line.

---

This gives a better understanding of the control sequence and syntax,

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do \
 ( \
  echo "$i starting ..."; \
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/disk$i bs=10M count=10; \
  echo "$i done ..."; \
 ) & \
done; wait
```

Comment: Since the OP tagged the question with Bash, you don't have to use `seq`. You can either do it as shown in the question or one of these ways: `for i in {1..5}` (Bash >= 3.0) or `for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))` (Bash >= 2.04). However, for compatibility with other shells, `seq` can be used, unless you're on a BSD system such as FreeBSD or OS X, then you need to use `jot`.

Comment: @Dennis, that quite collects the range options :-). I used `seq` from habit mostly... the `for` loops are good; `seq` lets you format easily, which may be the reason my mind sticks to it.

Comment: I want to make my scripts portable (POSIX) so they can be used on as many systems as possible. I'll go with `seq`. Thanks to all respondents.

Answer (score 2):

Add an ampersand (`&`) at the end of the `dd` command to make each one run in the background and add `; wait` after the `done`.

In some cases, `xargs --max-args=MAX-ARGS --max-procs=MAX-PROCS` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel http:// www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
seq 1 5 | parallel dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/disk{} bs=10M count=10
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ