# zero a large block device with parallelized dd

Tags: linux, dd, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

We have a sixty terabyte block device which we want to zero using dd.  Is it possible to parallelize this operation in order to reduce the amount of time it takes?

I've tried running the [following command](https://superuser.com/questions/142007/i-want-to-execute-the-commands-in-a-loop-at-the-same-time-not-one-after-another/179125#179125), but this is not quite what I'm looking for:

```
seq 1 5 | parallel dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/mydevice{} bs=10M count=10
```

Comment: Is it a single physical device?  HDD or SDD?

Comment: If it is a single HDD (which I guess it isn't, given the size), it won't be any faster, as the head will then have to move between the two write-positions. If it's an MD-array, you could destroy the array and run dd on the various disks in parallel. If it's a SAN disk or something like that, you are out of luck I guess, unless you use tooling from the SAN vendor.

Comment: It's an MD-array but we don't want to destroy the array.  We've got LVM and LUKS on top of the linux software RAID array.  We want to [allocate block data with zeros](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/) to ensure that the outside world will see this as random data i.e. protect against disclosure of usage patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seq 0 600000 | parallel dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/my60device bs=10M count=10 seek={}0
```

You already use `if, of, bs, and count` so I assume you know what they do.

`seek` seeks `n` blocks into the output file before doing the `dd`.

You do not write how the 60 TB device is physically arranged on spindles. That can have a huge impact. So this might be faster:

```
seq 0 60000 | parallel --shuf dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/my60device bs=10M count=100 seek={}00
```

It writes 1 GB blocks and shuffles the execution, which may speed up or slow down depending on the physical layout.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain the parameters?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to use --skip instead of --seek .   The former acting on the input, the latter acting on the output.  D'hoi!

Comment: As far as how the 60 terabyte block device is physically arranged on spindles: it's 12 SATA drives in a 6 Gbps SAS backplane with software linux RAID5 on top.

Comment: Then parallelizing output to the device will most likely not help: When you write block 1 and block n-1 at the same time, they will both cause all drives to be active = no good. So if you can, break the raid, dd on each device separately (parallel -j0 dd if=/dev/zero of={} bs=1M ::: /dev/sd... ) and after that re-create the raid.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try my home made parallel data write tool [pdd](https://github.com/Juan-Cortez3/pdd)
It works pretty well on NVMe drives.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you expand your answer a little with the "how" so it is more self-contained?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the underlying device driver supports scheduling two I/O operations at once through some bizzare `ioctl` stuff, you can't issue explicitly parallel I/O operations to a device.

`dd` is the wrong tool for that anyway since it works by writing data to a file or block device sequentially - the best you can do is tell it to write a large block size which lets the operating system optimize for sequential access better - which does improve the speed of things like writing to a tape.

Spinning two `dd`'s on a single block device won't change the fact that most I/O devices, especially things that look like disk drives, can really only do a single thing or small queue of things at once - and any optimization (i.e. leveraging NCQ) is done at the device driver level.

Comment: Yeah we've done performance tests with large arrays with/without NCQ in the past, but with a different hardware RAID controller and no LUKS encryption.

The last time we zero'd a 22 terabyte LUKS array it took about 8 hours.  I'm going to try @OleTange's suggestion and see if we can do better than 21 hours on a 60 terabyte array.